# How to find the duration from different row by the user id and the status in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to know how can I calculate the duration from the create_date column by the reference of the status column from stop to start for each user_id.

**start and stop table**

[image]

Comment: Does my answer suits your requirement? Please check & revert back...

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom column in same table using below **DAX** formula,

```
DateDiff CreateDate = 
DATEDIFF(
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(Table1[create_date])
        ,FILTER(
            ALL('Table1')
            ,'Table1'[user_id] = EARLIER(Table1[user_id]) && 'Table1'[create_date] < EARLIER(Table1[create_date])
        )
    ) 
    ,'Table1'[create_date]
    ,DAY
)
```

**The syntax for DATEDIFF function:**

```
DATEDIFF(<start_date>, <end_date>, <interval>)
```

> Note: Interval can be SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER,
>   YEAR based upon your need